# Need to embed another website into my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried different type of html tag called, iframe, embed,object to load external website. some of them loading fine, but some of them did't load.

I search my query in google, getting some result like, "For security reason some site may block iframe,embed, object "

All I want is, I need to load another website in my project. Is there any way to do this?

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<embed src="https://www.google.co.in/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</embed>

<object src="https://www.google.co.in/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</object>
```

when I tried those, showing error like  "https://www.google.co.in/ refused to connect."

Comment: Many security reasons why this won't work. What are you trying to achieve? Iframes won't work without permissions from the host of the site you're trying to embed. You could try doing a serverside GET request to retrieve the HTML to then populate a section of your site with, but any elements loaded in by scripts or source tags won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing **X-Frame-Options** header.
More informations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: This is used to avoid our project load in iframe right?